# android fit panel to bottom

Tags: android, vertical-alignment

I have a two buttons on my form, save and cancel. When I go to the form, the keyboard shows automatically. (Btw. Form has one EditText). I really dont know how to fit buttons to the bottom. Now buttons are placed below the EditText, I want put them above the keyboard.

For someone who want to see the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" style="@style/Form">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/etNewListNameForm" 
                android:hint="list name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"></EditText>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout style="@style/BottomPanel"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSaveCardList" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Save"></Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancelCardLst" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel"></Button>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

best regards

Images:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to use a relative layout instead of linear and use the alignParentBottom attribute, like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/etNewListNameForm" 
            android:hint="list name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"></EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout style="@style/BottomPanel"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        .....
```

Edit: It is also worth noting, you should very seriously consider using more descriptive names for your views. You've used descriptive names for your buttons and EditTexts but stuck with linearLayout1, and linearLayout2 for your layout views. Consider naming them something like mainLayout, and bottomPannelLayout or something and it will be easier down the road when you are trying to figure out how you've set it up.

Comment: yes I know but for now Im only practice component placing. I have problem with names, what the pattern should be? Something like this: FormName.Type.Name? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

In the LinearLayout containing your EditText, change `android:layout_height` to `0dp` and set `android:layout_weight` to `1`. That way it will eat up the rest of the space in the parent after the button panel takes its share.

```
...
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/etNewListNameForm" 
            android:hint="list name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"></EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your ScrollView in a RelativeLayout,
2. move the LinearLayout with the buttons to be the second child of that RelativeLayout,
3. and set android:layout_alignParentBottom to true for that LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary views and use relativeLayuot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0022">


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/btnSaveCardList"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/btnCancelCardLst"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="7dp" android:hint="list name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/etNewListNameForm"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this works very well but keyboard covers the buttons http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg706/scaled.php?server=706&filename=android3b.jpg&res=medium